# Why does Blender always export in inches

Tags: export, stl

I set my scene properties as MM but whenever I export a STL into say Prusa slicer it exports in inches?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try the Scene unit ticker under Export STL? - https://daler.github.io/blender-for-3d-printing/printing/export-stl.html

Comment: Yes I did try scene units, still did nothing. The solution below worked. Bit like Sketchup work in meters convert to mm.

Answer (score 2):

So I changed Blender to meters and export the STL object Scale x 10.
So a 2 meter cube exported as a STL imports into Prusa slicer as a 20mm cube.
I don't get the warning and I can work with that.